# Resumed GCD socket Source won't fire

Tags: macos, sockets, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I can't seem to accept TCP connections Grand Central Dispatch sources (`dispatch_source_t`)  and I can't understand what I could possibly be doing wrong.  I've gone through a lot of material and I'm still nowhere close ([Apple's own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html), [Mike Ash's blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/), etc.)

Of course, I could simply use third-party libraries (plenty on GitHub) but I'm trying to learn from this.  Thank you.

---

**I know the server is listening** on the port since using `telnet 127.0.0.1 6666` *times out* (but never actually connects) whereas any other port immediatly fails. The piece of code where I would `accept()` connections is never run.

```
class MyServer {
func startServing(#port: UInt16 = 6666) {

    // Create a listeningSocket on TCP/IPv4.
    println("\nStarting TCP server.\nCreating a listening Socket.")
    let listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 /*IPPROTO_TCP*/)
    if listeningSocket == -1 {
        println("Failed!")
        return
    }

    // Prepare an socket address.
    var no_sig_pipe: Int32 = 1
    setsockopt(listeningSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &no_sig_pipe, socklen_t(sizeof(Int32)))

    // Working around Swift's strict initialization policies
    var addr = sockaddr_in( sin_len: __uint8_t(sizeof(sockaddr_in))
                          , sin_family: sa_family_t(AF_INET)
                          , sin_port: CFSwapInt16HostToBig(port)
                          , sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: inet_addr("0.0.0.0"))
                          , sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) )
    var sock_addr = sockaddr( sa_len: 0
                            , sa_family: 0
                            , sa_data: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) )
    memcpy(&sock_addr, &addr, UInt(sizeof(sockaddr_in)))

    // bind() the socket to the address.
    println("Binding socket to \(port).")
    if bind(listeningSocket, &sock_addr, socklen_t(sizeof(sockaddr_in))) == POSIXSocketError {
        println("Failed!")
        close(listeningSocket)
        return
    }

    // If we still have a working socket at this point...
    if listeningSocket >= 0 {
        println("Creating GCD Source.")
        connectionSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, UInt(listeningSocket), 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0) /*serverQueue*/)

        if connectionSource == .None {
            println("Failed!")
            close(listeningSocket)
            return
        }

        let myself = self
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler( connectionSource, {
            // ***  This NEVER gets called!! ***
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { println("GCD Src fired.") })
            println("GCD Source triggered.")
            myself.acceptConnections(listeningSocket)
        })
        dispatch_resume(connectionSource)
    }
} // end func
} // end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to `listen` after you called `bind`. From [Mike Ash's blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-03-14-introduction-to-the-sockets-api.html):

> With the socket bound, the next step is to tell the system to listen
>   on it. This is done with, you guessed it, the listen function. It
>   takes two parameters: the socket to operate on, and the desired length
>   of the queue used for listening. This queue length tells the system
>   how many incoming connections you want it to sit on while trying to
>   hand those connections off to your program. Unless you have a good
>   reason to use something else, passing the SOMAXCONN gives you a safe,
>   large value.

So, after your `bind` call and error checking, and before you create your dispatch source, add something like:

```
if listen(listeningSocket, SOMAXCONN) != 0 {
    println("Listen Failed!")
    close(listeningSocket)
    return
}
```

I cobbled a quick test together with your code and the above change and this fires off a slew of `GCD Src fired.` and `GCD Source triggered.` messages when a connection to the socket is made.

Comment: Well crap!  I was aware about `listen()` but was convinced I had read somewhere that the `dispatch_source` was responsible for calling it.  In hindsight, it would make sense for it NOT to since `dispatch_source` may be bound to a file (for which you wouldn't call `listen()`)

Comment: I have the same problem as #user1040049. Both with what I pieced together and with a copy/paste of his and your path. If I add these snippets to an empty CML-application and add MyServer().startServing(); dispatch_main(); I encounter the same problem.